# I want to print all text inside seminar.txt file.by pointing to FileReader inside SeminarId function its showing to put try catch but other error came

Tags: java

CourseConsole class

```
public class CourseConsole {
private Course Course;
private Seminar seminar;
private InputStreamReader reader;
private BufferedReader br;
private File file;
public Writer output;



    private Scanner scanner;
    public Course inputCourse()  {
        System.out.println("======inputing the course======");
        //file = new File("Files1/Courses.txt");
          //Creating a Scanner object
          //Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
          
        scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        Course course = new Course();
        CourseId(course);
        CourseName(course);
        Coursefee(course);
        SeminarId(course);
        return course;
        
        
        
    }
    public void CourseId(Course course) {
        {
            
            System.out.println("Please enter the Course No:");
            try {
                course.setId(scanner.nextInt());
                if (course.getId() == 0) {
                    CourseId(course);
                    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid value!");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            
                System.out.println("Incorrect data");
                course.setId(0);
            }
            System.out
                    .println("==================================================================================");
        }

    }
    public void CourseName(Course course) {
        System.out.println(" enter the Course name:");
        try {
            course.setName(scanner.next());

            if (course.getName() == null
                    || course.getName().trim().equals("")) {
                CourseName(course);
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid value!");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            
            System.out.println("Your data format is incorrect:");
            course.setName(null);
            
        }
        System.out
                .println("==================================================================================");
    }
    public void Coursefee(Course course) {
        System.out.println("enter the Course fee");
        try {
            course.setfees(scanner.nextInt());
            if (course.getfees() == 0) {
                Coursefee(course);
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid value!");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        
            System.out.println("Incorrect data");
            course.setId(0);
        }
        System.out
                .println("==================================================================================");
    }
    public void SeminarId(Course course) {
        {
            file=new File("Files1/seminar.txt");
            FileReader i =new FileReader(file); 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(i);
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
            
            System.out.println("==================================================================================");
    
        }

    }
    
            
        
    }
```

I want to print everything inside seminar.txt file but unable to do it.Its done inside SeminarId function.It asks to put a try catch when pointing in filereader and readLine and in.close.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException

Answer (score 0):

```
public Course inputCourse()  {
        System.out.println("======inputing the course======");
        //file = new File("Files1/Courses.txt");
          //Creating a Scanner object
          //Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
          
        scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        Course course = new Course();
        CourseId(course);
        CourseName(course);
        Coursefee(course);
        //Course path = new Course();
        Seminar("Files1/seminar.txt");
        return course;
        
        
        
    }

public Course inputCourse()  {
        System.out.println("======inputing the course======");
        //file = new File("Files1/Courses.txt");
          //Creating a Scanner object
          //Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
          
        scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        Course course = new Course();
        CourseId(course);
        CourseName(course);
        Coursefee(course);
        //Course path = new Course();
        Seminar("Files1/seminar.txt");
        return course;
        
        
        
    }
   public void Seminar(String path) {
        {
                try {
                System.out.println("======Reading from the file======");
                fr = new FileReader(path);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                String s;
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(s);

                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                    fr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

   System.out.println("==================================================================================");
        }}
```

By doing this you can print all elements in seminar.txt